# Changing accessoryView in tableview one by one in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi after I set default icons for cells, I want to change default icons to little screenshots. Screenshots I am becoming from a server one by one and I am creating UIImages from theese.
My problem is, that i dont know how to change the accessoryView in concrete cells.

My code from for-cycle is here:

```
// after I got a bytmap with the screenshot 
UIImage *imageCopy = [ImageHelper convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:newBitmap withWidth:width withHeight:height];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageCopy];
UITableViewCell *myCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) i];
myCell.accessoryView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

Problem is I think, with line:

```
UITableViewCell *myCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh table after changes:

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

If it still doesn't change the image there is a probleme in your allocations.

Comment: the app is crashing at line with the problem

Comment: is your i an int? You cannot cast an int to NSIndexPath

Comment: NSLog the values of NSIndexPath and MyCell. It looks like a bad reference/nil problem.

Comment: Problem was the casting the integer "i" to indexpath. THANX

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would write a subclass of a `UITableViewCell` which holds url to your screenshot. Then, as they download you can call `UITableView`'s metod `visibleCells` which returns an array of visible cells. Comparing the url where the image came from and your cell subclasses' url property you can set the proper `accesoryView` for the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with this line:

```
UITableViewCell *myCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1] ];
```

Thanx for user: inovaction